# how can insert array consisting of multiple objects using sequelize and node?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

In below block line of code i want to insert an array of multiple object. but it's not working.

```
let Bookarray = [{author:"john matt", BookName:"Beauty of Nature"},
{author:"Mick Foley", BookName:"Have A Nice Day"},
{author:"Kevin Sullivan.", BookName:"WWE 50"},
{author:"Brian Shields And Dean Miller", BookName:"35 Years Of Wrestlemania"},
{author:"Mick Foley", BookName:"Foley Is Good"},
]
 
let InsertObj = await BooksDetails.create(Bookarray);
```

What should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an array containing multiples objects use bulkCreate.

```
let InsertObj = await BooksDetails.bulkCreate(Bookarray);
```